# Dart find string value in a list using contains

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of numbers like below -

```
List contacts = [14169877890, 17781231234, 14161231234];
```

Now I want to find if one of the above list element would contain the below string value -

```
String value = '4169877890';
```

I have used list.any to do the search, but the below print statement inside the if condition is not printing anything.

```
if (contacts.any((e) => e.contains(value))) {
     print(contacts[0]);
}
```

I am expecting it to print out the first element of the contacts list as it partially contains the string value.

What is it I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if contacts is an integer and value is a string on purpose or mistake, but this works in dart pad if you convert it to string:

```
if (contacts.any((e) => e.toString().contains(value))) {
     print(contacts[0]);
}
```

[DartPad Link.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3d547fa15849f9794b7dbb8627499b00)

Comment: You probably intend `e.toString() == value`.  If you use `contains`, then `'123'` would be "found" in `[1234]`.

Comment: I thought so, but `Error: The method 'contains' isn't defined for the class 'int'.`

Comment: Huh? I'm telling you to *not* use `contains`.

Comment: So I made sure every single value in that list and list itself is a string. Also made sure the value I am searching for inside the list is also a string.

Comment: Finally found the issue, Thanks to all who helped figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`contacts` isn't a `List<String>`, so your any search can't be true, you need turn element of `contracts` to string to able to use `contains`.

```dart
void main() {
  var contacts = [14169877890, 17781231234, 14161231234];
  print(contacts.runtimeType);
  var value = '4169877890';
  print(value.runtimeType);
  var haveAnyValid = contacts.any((element) {
    return "$element".contains(value);
  });
  print(haveAnyValid);
  
  // result

  // JSArray<int>
  // String
  // true
}
```

Comment: I checked the runtimetype, it says contacts is a dynamic list and those values are pulled in from an api call.

Comment: If you make sure it is a **List of String** using type cast, or just use `toString()` or `"$value"` to turn them to `String` before use `contacts`

Comment: Yes I made it a list of strings, now I see the runtimetype as String. Still I haven't been able to make it work.