# Find values in the list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I return values filtering from this list?

I used contains, but it displays all the values.

I want to retrieve items from the list that have the word "abc" like this -> `abc Item`. The ones that have other words grouped like this
-> `abcde Item`, should be ignored.

I tried adding spaces to match the items in the list, but it didn't work:

.contains(' ${text} '.toUpperCase())

.contains('\n${text}\n'.toUpperCase())

```dart
List data = [{"Label": "abc Item", "Value": 10}, {"Label": "abcde Item", "Value": 20},{"Label": "edabc Item", "Value": 20}, {"Label": "item abc", "Value": 20}];

List match = [];
String text ="abc";
    
match.addAll(
  data.where(
    (oldValue) => oldValue['Label']
      .toString()
      .toUpperCase()
      .contains(text.toUpperCase()),
  ),
);
    
print(match);
```

**expected values of the list search:**

```
[{"Label": "abc Item", "Value": 10}, {"Label": "item abc", "Value": 20}]
```

Comment: Are you asking a question? Or just announcing?

Comment: Sorry, I adjusted the title

Comment: Okay, but you're still not saying what the problem is. Does your code not work? If not, why? What error message are you getting? What results are displaying? Are they the wrong results? People will help, but they don't want to have to guess what you need help with.

Comment: @Felipe use firstWhere() instead of where()

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022906/dart-find-string-value-in-a-list-using-contains

Answer (score -1):

try this for individual index or dynamic list to create

```
List<Student> studentsDataList = [];
  
  Student std = Student();
    std.Label = "oneLabel";
    std.Value = 40;
    studentsDataList.add(std);

    std.Label = "twoLabel";
    std.Value = 80;
    studentsDataList.add(std);
  
    print(studentsDataList.length);
```

model class for students

```
class Student {
   String? Label;
   int? Value;

  Student({this.Label, this.Value,});

  Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Label = json['Label'];
    Value = json['Value'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Label'] = this.Label;
    data['Value'] = this.Value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: kindly, read the question :)

Answer (score -1):

```
void main()
{
  List data = [{"Label": "abc Item", "Value": 10}, {"Label": "abcde Item", "Value": 20},{"Label": "edabc Item", "Value": 20}];
  
  List match = [];


  
  
  match.addAll(data.where((oldValue)=>oldValue["Label"]=="abc Item"));
  
  print(match);
}
```

This is your Ans:
please try this.

Comment: kindly, avoid answering duplicate questions :)

Comment: also, this doesn't answer the OP's question :)